# Why AJAX call to Servlet (async) is executed multiple times?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets, asynchronous

I'm doing a simple login application with servlets and AJAX. I'm curious why the AJAX call is fired multiple times when I specified async as true. When async is specified as false, the call is made just one time.

Sample:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="flogin" class="panel">
        <section class="panel-head">

        </section>
        <section class="panel-body">
            <input type="text" id="txt-username" class="textbox" placeholder="Usuario o email"/>
            <input type="password" id="txt-password" class="textbox" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
            <section class="form-action-group">
                <button type="submit" id="btn-login" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresar</button>
            </section>
        </section>
    </form>

    <script src="assets/js/login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript source:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

function init() {
    var form = document.querySelector("#flogin");
    form.addEventListener("submit", handleLogin, true);

    function handleLogin(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var txtUsername = document.querySelector("#txt-username");
        var txtPassword = document.querySelector("#txt-password");

        var userdata = '{"username":'+txtUsername.value+',"password":'+txtPassword.value+'}';

        loginByAjax(userdata);
        resetForm(form);
    }

    function loginByAjax(data) {
        var message;
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", "LoginController", false);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(request.readyState != 4 || request.status != 200) {
                message = request.responseText;
            } else {
                message = request.responseText;
            }
            console.log(message);
        };
        request.send("userdata="+data);
    }

}
```

And the servlet:

```
package com.company.controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.company.utils.JsonUtils;

@WebServlet(asyncSupported=true, urlPatterns={"/LoginController"})
public class LoginController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("LoginLogger");

    public LoginController() {
        super();
    }

    public void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        String strJson = request.getParameter("userdata");
        Map<String, Object> userData = JsonUtils.getMapFrom(strJson);
        String username = (String) userData.get("username");
        String password = (String) userData.get("password");

        if(username.equals("Duke") && password.equals("Duke777")) {
            writer.print("Usuario correctamente identificado");
        } else {
            writer.print("Usuario o contraseña incorrectas");
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch(ServletException | IOException e) {
            logger.warning(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch(ServletException | IOException e) {
            logger.warning(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Async AJAX call image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUGaq.png

Can someone explain to me why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The true is the servlet is not called multiple times, what happen is when you make an async call the onreadystatechange will be called several times during the ajax request phase, since the connection is stablished until the connection is closed, there are 4 steps in the ajax call and each of them call the onreadystatechange you can know the step with the request.readyState:

- 0: request not initialized
- 1: server connection established
- 2: request received
- 3: processing request
- 4: request finished and response is ready

You're logging the message in each of these steps you could log at the message at the end of the ajax call in this way.

```
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {//if finish the ajax call and the status is ok
       message = request.responseText;
       console.log(message);
   };
   console.message('Checking the progress of the ajax call: ' + request.readyState);
}
```

Your could check more information in the MDN [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciated it so much.

This:

`if(request.readyState == 4 || request.status == 200)`

Should be:

`if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)`

for last response. Greetings ^^

Comment: You're welcome, yes totally right, I updated my answer was copy and paste mistake thanks for pointing it out.